# In Excel, using VBA, is there a way to map, store, and reapply formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

So, I've got a report that I want to make sure has the correct format regardless if the format is changed by the user or by excel -- is there a way to "auto-map" the current formatting of a document (it's fine if it's mapped on a cell-by-cell basis), store it in a macro so I'm able to use it later?

Comment: If you don't specify what features you want to map, the question is too broad, and probably the answers are not going to satisfy you. (Fonts? Number format? Borders? Colors? Conditional formatting? Charts Format? Page breaks? Paper size? Table formats? Pivots? ... )

Comment: @belisarius: +1 True, my preference would be to gets dump of ALL non-default formatting configs, so that I'm able to decide what's important, and what's not. No idea if that's possible, but that's what I'm looking for. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: OK. I understand, but too broad for me. Tagging as favorite to see if someone comes up with anything. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a new worksheet
2. Select the entire (original) worksheet
3. Copy it
4. Now select A1 of the new worksheet you made in step 1
5. Choose Paste Special (it's on the dropdown menu to the right of Paste)
6. Choose Formats

You've now made a blank spreadsheet that contains all the formatting from the first spreadsheet. You can now copy | paste special formats from this new spreadsheet back to your original spreadsheet at will.

Answer (score 2):

You need a copy of the report in its unaltered state.  You can use a hidden sheet in the same workbook or use a sheet in a separate workbook.  When you want to "reset" the formatting to the default, you would do something like this

```
shBackup.UsedRange.Copy
shReport.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

There are a couple of problems with this method.  Column widths aren't pasted with formats, so if that's something users can change, you'll need another method of storing those.  The larger challenge may be when to create shBackup, but hopefully your existing code makes it obvious.

If the user can change the UsedRange by, say, inserting rows or columns in shReport, the above code wouldn't do the trick.  But I think that goes back to when you create the backup copy.

The basis of this is that Excel already has the infrastructure to hold all of the settings you want.  It has Range objects, Font objects, Interior objects, etc.  So rather than roll your own mapping structure, use what Excel already has to store all the properties.